# Looking for an example of quotient ring isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-isomorphism

In a homework problem,  I need to find an example of quotient ring isomorphism $\frac{R}{I}\cong\frac{R}{J}$ such that $I\neq J$. I think that it is a common issue but I am not pretty sure about it...

I have been reading about this issue and I have found that if I take any polynomial ring $R=K[X]$ for some field $K$, if I consider the ideal $I=(X)$ and the ideal $J=(X-1)$ then $\frac{R}{I}\cong\frac{R}{J}\cong K$.

It is true? Could you give me a specific example with a little clarification or comment?

Comment: Your example is true and correct with K the real numbers

Comment: @AndresMejia and how could I define the isomorphism $\frac{\mathbb{R}[X]}{(X)}\cong\frac{\mathbb{R}[X]}{(X-1)}$?

Answer (score 1):

For $a\in \mathbb{R}$, fuction: $$\phi_a:\mathbb{R}[x]\to \mathbb{R}:\phi_a(p(x)):=p(a)$$
is a ring homeomorphism:
$$\phi_a(p(x)+q(x))=p(a)+q(a)=\phi_a(p(x))+\phi_a(q(x))$$
$$\phi_a(p(x)q(x))=p(a)q(a)=\phi_a(p(x))\phi_a(q(x)).$$
Also:

$$\mathrm{Ker}\,\phi_a=\{p(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]:\phi_a(p(x))=p(a)=0\}=
\{p(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]:x-a | p(x)\}=<x-a>$$

and 
$$\mathrm{Im}\,\phi_a=\{\phi_a(p(x))=p(a): p(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]\}=\mathbb{R}.$$
So function: $$\mu_a:\frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{<x-a>}\to \mathbb{R}:\mu_a\big(p(x)+<x>\big)=p(a)$$ is a ring isomorphism. 
So $$\frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{<x-a>} \cong \frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{<x-b>}\cong \mathbb{R},$$
while $<x-a>\neq <x-b>$ for $a\neq b.$

Answer (score 0):

Yes note that since K is a field K[x] is an Euclidean domain. Now map you want to consider is sending polynomial to its remainder. (This is almost an answer  I won't elaborate more as this is a homework.)

Comment: Ok, but... what advantage does $K[X] $be a euclidean domain? It is necessary?

Comment: To talk about remainder properly you need division algorithm. ED provide you a division algorithm.